# Setting the height of borders

Tags: html, css

I have two questions:

1. Can I set the border-right's height?
2. Can I hide the last li's border-right?

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 30px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  border-right: 1px solid #aba;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>product</li>
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>about</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the border for the last `li`, use the pseudo-class `:last-child`

I used `display:flex` and `align-item:center` after adding a margin to the top and bottom of the `li` to center it

```css
body {

    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#banner {

    height:30px;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: aquamarine;
}
#banner ul{

    list-style: none;
    height:30px;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#banner ul li {

    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    border-right:1px solid #aba;
    margin-top:10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#banner ul li:last-child {
  border-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="banner">
    <ul >
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>product</li>
        <li>phone</li>
        <li>cat</li>
        <li>about</li>
    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Instead of a border you can experiment with ::before and ::after

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
}
li {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: gray;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px; /* control the 'height' with top/bottom */
  bottom: 5px;
  right: 0;
  width: 5px; /*same as what your border was */
  background-color: black; /* instead of border-color */
}
li:last-child::after { /*hides last 'border' */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

2. Try #banner ul li:last-child { border-right: 0; or border-right-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0);}

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Hastig/kkx33des/

Answer (score 2):

### Hide the last border

This is your border:

```
li { border-right: 1px solid #aba; }
```

But you don't want it to appear on the last item. So try this instead:

```
li + li {
  border-left: 1px solid #aba;
}
```

The new rule applies a left-side border to `li` elements that come immediately after another `li`. This will exclude a left border on the first `li` and a right border on the last `li`.

---

### Shorter borders

You want the borders to be less than full height. You can achieve the effect with absolutely-positioned pseudo-elements:

```
li {
  position: relative; /* establish the containing block for abspos children */
}

li+li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner {
  height: 30px;
  width: 750px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#banner ul {
  list-style: none;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 0;
}

#banner ul li {
  float: left;
  margin: auto 0;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  /* border-right: 1px solid #aba; */
  position: relative;
}

li+li::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  height: 50%;
  width: 2px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>link</li>
    <li>product</li>
    <li>phone</li>
    <li>cat</li>
    <li>about</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try This :**

```
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border-right: 3px solid orange;
  height: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

**Full Code :**

```css
  body {

    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
}

#banner {

    height:30px;
    width: 750px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: aquamarine;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#banner ul{

    list-style: none;
    height:30px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;

}

#banner ul li {

    float: left;
    margin: auto 0;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 100px;
    text-align:center;
}
li:not(:last-child):after {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
  border-right: 3px solid orange;
  height: 20px;
  top: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
 <div id="banner">
    <ul >
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>link</li>
        <li>product</li>
        <li>phone</li>
        <li>cat</li>
        <li>about</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

1. U can try pipe symbol as an alternaten using :after selector of each li
2. You need :last-child pseudo Css selector to hide the border of last li

Comment: How to do with the first (try pipe symbol as an alternaten)?

Comment: The pipe that he is talking about is this = |